# Connecting ElectrumX to external Bitcoin Core node

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum-server

I have a (full) Bitcoin Core node on a Raspberry Pi (Umbrel) and I'm looking for a way to connect an ElectrumX install to it. Is this possible?

Comment: OK, I found it I think. You can type it in the electrumx.conf file.

Comment: Hi Bart DV, could you please elaborate what you needed to do so other users finding your question will get the full answer here?